# How to emulate pandas.DataFrame indexing from within a custom class?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to define a class which does not inherit from `pandas.DataFrame` but sometimes acts like it. For example, I can do:

```
import pandas
import numpy

class FalseDF(object):
    def __init__(self, df):
        self.df = df

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return self.df.__getitem__(item)


df = pandas.DataFrame(numpy.reshape(numpy.arange(10), (2, 5)))
print(df)
```

which gives:

```
   0  1  2  3  4
0  0  1  2  3  4
1  5  6  7  8  9
```

and now:

```
fdf = FalseDF(df)
print(fdf[3])
```

gives:

```
0    3
1    8
Name: 3, dtype: int64
```

How can I now make the following syntax also work?

```
    print(fdf.iloc[1])
```

or

```
    print(fdf.loc[2])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might not capture all the behavior of a `DataFrame`, but for starters you could implement [`__getattr__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__) or, much more risky, [`__getattribute__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattribute__) to pass on requests for attributes to the underlying dataframe:

```
class FalseDF:
    def __getattr__(self, key):
        return getattr(self.df, key)
```